# Dissolving overlapping polygons without common attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, dissolve, polygon-creation

In QGIS 3.20 I have clusters of overlapping polygons as shown in the image below:

[image: Clusters of overlapping polygons]

My requirement is to dissolve each of these clusters into single polygons. While the "Dissolve" tool provides me with the required **visual** output as shown below, it ends up merging all the polygons (of all the clusters) together into a single feature.

[image: Result when 'Dissolve' is used]

The polygons in each cluster **don't share a common attribute** so I can't dissolve by attribute either. The full set is also too large in number for me to select them manually.

How do I dissolve based on whether or not the polygons overlap with each other?

Comment: 1. Dissolve, 2. Multipart to single parts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume there are nine features in the *'grid_test'* (reddish) layer, see the image below.

[image: input]

Use the the GDAL's ["Dissolve"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorgeoprocessing.html#dissolve) (`GDAL > Vector geoprocessing > Dissolve`) from the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Tick the *'Produce one feature for each geometry in any kind of geometry collection in the second source'* in Advance Parameters.

[image: dissolve_param]

Press <kbd>Run</kbd> and get the output like this:

[image: result]

Comment: First, "Geometry Column name" field can't be "geometry" in your example. It throws an error about not having a field with that name. 
In any other setting, I could not reproduce the same result as you presented with that algorithm.

Comment: What kind of error ?