# Merging polygons only if three or more are on top of each other in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, overlapping-features, dissolve

I am working on a layer with many polygons (circles). I would like to create a polygon containing only the areas where 3 or more circles overlap (in my example there would be only 1 area in the east). Each circle has a specific `"ID"`.

I don't know if QGIS allows such specific conditions.

[image: Example]

Comment: You might try the SAGA polygon self intersection tool, then select for records with more than two IDs in the ID field.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

You can use QGIS expressions with either [Geometry generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (see here for [details and differences between these two options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)). Use this expression with Geometry generator (see below for Geometry by expression) and replace `@layer` with the name of your polygon layer:

```
with_variable (
    'poly',
    array_foreach (
        case
        when 
            array_length(
                overlay_intersects(
                    @layer, 
                    $geometry, limit:=-1
                )
            ) = 2
        then
            overlay_intersects(
                @layer, 
                $geometry, limit:=-1
            )
        end,
        intersection (
            $geometry,
            @element
        )
    ),
    intersection (
        array_get (@poly,0),
        array_get (@poly,1)
    )
)
```

If you use the expression with Geometry by expression, use this expression, where you have to replace `poly` in lines 8 and 14 with the name of your polygon layer:

```
with_variable (
    'poly',
    array_foreach (
        case
        when 
            array_length(
                overlay_intersects(
                    'poly', 
                    $geometry, limit:=-1
                )
            ) = 3
        then
            overlay_intersects(
                'poly', 
                $geometry, limit:=-1
            )
        end,
        intersection (
            $geometry,
            @element
        )
    ),
    intersection (
        array_get (@poly,1),
        array_get (@poly,2)
    )
)
```

*Red hached area created with Geometry generator:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you Babel. Is there a way that I could select the wanted area? My goal would be to copy paste the area meeting the condition into another shapefile. I tried to use your expression in "select with an expression" but it didn't work there.

For those with the same issue, don't forget to use QGIS 3.16.

Comment: See updated answer, the second expression

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'test'* with six features in it, see image below.

[image: input]

### Solution #1. Getting the feature with three and more overlaps

This solution was partially derived from @johns's comment

**Step 1.** Perform an intersection by means of the SAGA's ["Polygon Self-Intersection"](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.1.4/shapes_polygons_12.html) geoalgorithm

[image: step_11]

**Step 2.** Use the ["Extract by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-expression) geoalgorithm with the following expression:

```
array_length(string_to_array("ID", delimiter:='|')) >= 3
```

[image: step_21]

and get the output

[image: result1]

### Solution #2. Dissolving only features that contain a feature with three and more overlaps

**Step 1.** Create a field `"test"` with this expression:

```
array_sum(overlay_intersects(@layer, 1))
```

[image: step_12]

**Step 2.** Use the the GDAL's ["Dissolve"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorgeoprocessing.html#dissolve) (`GDAL > Vector geoprocessing > Dissolve`) from the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) with field `"test"` from the *Step 1*, and do not forget to tick the *Produce one feature for each geometry in any kind of geometry collection in the source file*.

[image: step_22]

Press <kbd>Run</kbd> and get the output

[image: result2]

---

**References:**

- [Dissolving overlapping polygons without common attribute in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407427/dissolving-overlapping-polygons-without-common-attribute-in-qgis)

Comment: Hello Taras, I see that my question wasn't clear enough. I want to only have the area where 3 or more polygon are overlapping. As shown in the example of Babel. I'll be more specific next time.

Comment: Okay! I think I got you now @_@

Answer (score 2):

1. Convert the polygons to lines with [Polygon to lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#index-15).
2. Split the polygons with the lines from 1: [Split with lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines).
3. Create a [Buffer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#buffer) with a very small, ***negative*** distance from the output of step 2.
4. Check within how many of the initial polygons the output geometries of step 3 are: create a new field called `within` using [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) with this expression (replace `poly` with the name of the initial polygon layer): `array_length (overlay_within ('poly', $id))`.
5. Go back to the layer created in step 2. Use [Select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) with the following expression: `array_first (overlay_contains ('Buffered', "within")) >=3` (adapt the number for how many overlapping polygons you want to have).

Now the parts that have 3 or more overlaps are selected - you can copy and paste them to a new layer. Don't forget that you have duplicate geometries: use [Delete duplicate geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicate-geometries).

*Area where 3 or more polygons overlap (hatched in pink):*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So, if I understand your question correctly, follow me.

My initial data is a layer called "buf" type - multipolygons;

1. Polygons in simple polygons - Vector->Processing geometry->Split composite objects with saving layer "buf_parts", see figure 1;
   [image]

Figure 1

2. Next, polygons into lines, see Figure 2;

[image]

Figure 2

3. Then analysis tools->Vector-Overlay->Cut with lines, see figure 3;

[image]

Figure 3

Result

[image]

Figure 4

4. Then create centroids for each of the split parts and save the result, named as "center_parts", see the result shown in figure 4;

[image]

Figure 4

5. Next, Layer->Create Layer->New Virtual Layer, import the results of steps 1 and 4 and run the SQL script, see figure 5 (it will help you count the number of points that fall into the composite circles);

[image]

Figure 5

```
SELECT count(*) cnt, b.geometry from "center_parts" a JOIN "buf_parts" b ON st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry) group by b.geometry
```

6. Next, run the following SQL-script on the "virtual_layer", with saving the result in the layer "buf_sel" , see figure 6 (in this case, we work with copies of points, based on the number of intersections);

[image]

Figure 6

```
SELECT cnt, geometry from "buf_sel" WHERE cnt>='8'
```

7. Next, on the layer "buf_sel" run the SQL-script, which combines the circles in common polygons and this is your final result, be sure to save it and then act yourself :-).

[image]

Figure 7

```
SELECT cnt, st_union(geometry) geom FROM "buf_sel"
```

Result

[image]

Figure 8

Original spatial solutions...

Comment: I though you gonna add your famous translator: Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version) @_@

Comment: @Taras, Sometimes, when I post my question-answer, the link is added automatically, sometimes not :-)...+1 to whom this answer became clear :-), the main thing is to understand the idea...

Answer (score 2):

Using the `Union` Geoprocessing tool is probably the fastest way:

1. Run `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Union`
2. On the output of step 1, use [Select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression) with this expression to select those parts where 3 or more polygon overlap: `array_length (overlay_equals(@layer, $id))+1 >=3`

*Blue circles = output of `Union`. The labels are created by the expression above (minus the `>=3` part) and shows how many polygons overlap in each part. Highlighted in yellow: polygons selected as described in step 2:*
[image]